# Creating a Many-to-Many Relationship Using Spring Roo

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, spring-roo

Can anyone direct me how to create a many-to-many relationship using the spring roo framework? I've been trying to implement this relationship and can't seem to get through with it. Anyone knows of any links where i can find more info will be greatly appreciated or if you could lend some support would also be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks alot...

According to the thread... it suggested to do two field set...that creates two joint tables from both side... I did a little more research and came across this thread
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=74203

Which itself was doing the same... i then decided to do a field set from one side since i wanted to acieve a uni-directional relationship

Answer (score 3):

There are some challenges with getting this working on the UI side.  Have a look at this forum post:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=84034

It provides a decent work-around.